# Powershell replacing string with multiple values

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell. Here are some code examples will help me to explain:

The first example gives the correct output I want which is a list of values, two values in this example, under OrganizationalUnitDistinguishedNames

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop> $test=Get-APSDirectoryConfigList -DirectoryName test.com
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop> $test

CreatedTime          DirectoryName OrganizationalUnitDistinguishedNames ServiceAccountCredentials
-----------          ------------- ------------------------------------ -------------------------
12/4/2017 9:26:50 AM test.com      {OU=t1,DC=acc, OU=t2,DC=test}        Amazon.AppStream.Model.ServiceAccountCredentials


PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop> $test.OrganizationalUnitDistinguishedNames
OU=t1,DC=acc
OU=t2,DC=test
```

However, the following command treats two values "OU=t2,DC=test,OU=t1,DC=acc" as a single string. What is the correct syntax to create with two separate values instead of a single string? I have tried different ways (with or without double quotes), they don't work.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop> $test=New-APSDirectoryConfig -DirectoryName test.com -OrganizationalUnitDistinguishedName "OU=t2,DC=test,OU=t1,DC=acc" -ServiceAcco
untCredentials_AccountName TEST\serviceaccount -ServiceAccountCredentials_AccountPassword secret_password
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop> $test

CreatedTime          DirectoryName OrganizationalUnitDistinguishedNames ServiceAccountCredentials
-----------          ------------- ------------------------------------ -------------------------
12/4/2017 9:33:25 AM test.com      {OU=t2,DC=test,OU=t1,DC=acc}         Amazon.AppStream.Model.ServiceAccountCredentials


PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop> $test.OrganizationalUnitDistinguishedNames
OU=t2,DC=test,OU=t1,DC=acc
```

Answer (score 2):

### Try:

```
$OUDNArray = @("OU=t2,DC=test","OU=t1,DC=acc")
$test=New-APSDirectoryConfig -DirectoryName test.com -OrganizationalUnitDistinguishedName $OUDNArray -ServiceAccountCredentials_AccountName TEST\serviceaccount -ServiceAccountCredentials_AccountPassword T3st12345
```

According to the [AWS Appstream Docs:](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/New-APSDirectoryConfig.html)

> **Parameters**
>
> **-OrganizationalUnitDistinguishedName <String[]>** 
> The distinguished names of the organizational units for computer accounts.
>   Required? False Position? Named Accept pipeline input?    False

The `OrganizationalUnitDistinguishedName` accepts an array.